# display the result of a select query

Tags: postgresql

Do you have any idea about how to display the result of the following query or store it in a table :

```
do
 $$
declare 
 i record;
begin

  for i in 1..3 loop
   PERFORM ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
    sub_query.*
   FROM line AS b, LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT a.id) AS old_id,
       ST_Union(a.geom) AS fusion
   FROM line AS a
   WHERE a.id > b.id
   AND ST_touches(a.geom, b.geom) = true 
   AND a.material = b.material

   GROUP BY a.material

   ) AS sub_query
   ;
  end loop;
  end;
  $$
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you use record in code above, so just run three times:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
    sub_query.*
   FROM line AS b, LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT a.id) AS old_id,
       ST_Union(a.geom) AS fusion
   FROM line AS a
   WHERE a.id > b.id
   AND ST_touches(a.geom, b.geom) = true 
   AND a.material = b.material

   GROUP BY a.material

   ) AS sub_query
   ;
```

?..

and if you are asking theoretically, use `raise` to output the values or `insert into` to put them to the table...

Comment: I need to execute the query 3 times that's why i added the record.

Comment: without context I dont understand why you don't just select three times...

Comment: My query is a spatial process and I need to do it 3 times. So I put the whole query inside of a loop. So you told me to execute it three times and no need for the pgplsql. But I don't see how to do it and store in a table.

Comment: I did it and it gave me the same result every time the query is executed, but what I want is repeat the process of the union and have different results each time it is fired. When you execute a select 3 times or more you get the same result and this not what I'm expecting

Comment: Why do you expect the same statement to return different results each time you run it?

Comment: I know that it would return the same result but I'm wondering if there's a way to repeat the process of the union several times.